# React App: Despite a POST request, the body info is displayed in URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new new to React. I am creating the Signin and Register components that let the user signin and register to the main app.
But, whenever I click on signin/ register button, the route changes to home (as it should) but then the app reboots and it goes through constructor again, making the route signin again. Because of this, I can see just a flash of my main home screen and again it goes to signin page.

Also, despite using the post request, the information that I put in for email and password is displayed in URL after I click on signin/ register.

I am unable to understand what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You aren't preventing the default submit button event action. Change your submit handler to include `onSubmitSignIn = (event) => { event.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped the first part of my problem. I am still facing the issue of my username and password displaying in URL despite using POST in both signin.js and register.js. Can you please take a look at that as well?

Comment: You should look into react router. That may help with routing in your app. Using state to track routing is probably not a great way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch method must be in capital letters

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options